# RegEx Matching and Separation Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm working with a system that has a text value that could be in one of the following formats:

- ABCD
- F1000
- 1000
- 1000A
- F1000A

In most cases, if there's a letter preceding or following the digits, there will only be one letter, but that isn't guaranteed.

I was trying to create some regex expressions for grabbing the preceding text, the numerals, and the trailing text. However, the best I can come up with doesn't match very well and requires me to then break down the matches even further based on the match results. Each of these three different values has to go into their own bucket in a database.

I'm good with figuring out the numerals-only matches, but it's trying to break apart the mixed values that I can't seem to get properly, and I can't seem to get the text-only matches. Am I just best off matching the letter number pairs and then grabbing the pieces I want?

At present, these are the regular expressions I have come up with:

```
var regex0 = /[A-z]+?![0-9]/;
var regex1 = /[A-z]+[0-9]+/;
var regex2 = /[0-9]+/;
var regex3 = /[0-9]+[A-z]+/;
```

- regex0 is supposed to get a text-only match but doesn't work.
- regex1 appropriately gets a match when there's text followed by numbers.
- regex2 successfully gets only the numerals.
- regex3 appropriately gets a match when there are numbers followed by text.

For `regex1` and `regex3`, I have no problem with doing an extra match to just pull the text from the match, but I'm hoping that there's a way to do it all in one shot.

Comment: An advice: don't loose your time with useless experimentations until you take the time to read a regex tutorial. This will save your life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use 3 captured groups:

```
/^(\D*)(\d*)(\D*)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF8cX5/1)

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- `[A-Z]{4}` matches `ABCD`
- `[A-Z]\d{4}` matches `F1000`
- `\d{4}` matches `1000`
- `\d{4}[A-Z]` matches `1000A`
- `[A-Z]\d{4}[A-Z]` matches `F1000A`

Comment: This doesn't particularly work considering it focuses too much on the given examples. The number of alpha and numeric characters can vary by quite a bit in the environment in which this needs to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Use a qualified character ahead as a pseudo anchor.
The other parts are optional, but will match something because it's qualified.

`(?=[A-Za-z\d])([A-Za-z]*)(\d*)([A-Za-z]*)`

Expanded

```
 (?= [A-Za-z\d] )              # Assert a qualified character is ahead
 ( [A-Za-z]* )                 # (1)
 ( \d* )                       # (2)
 ( [A-Za-z]* )                 # (3)
```

Matches

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 4 ) 
ABCD  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 5 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 5 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

-------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 8 , len 1 ) 
F  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 9 , len 4 ) 
1000  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 13 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

-------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 16 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 16 , len 4 ) 
1000  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 20 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

-------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 23 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 23 , len 4 ) 
1000  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 27 , len 1 ) 
A  

-------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 31 , len 1 ) 
F  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 32 , len 4 ) 
1000  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 36 , len 1 ) 
A
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for, but the previous answer gives the same results with a bit more simplicity. I still upvoted because it did the trick.

Comment: Also, [A-Za-z] can be written as [A-z] and make the same matches. Wasn't sure if you were aware of that.

Comment: @MichaelMcCauley -  Doesn't bother me you accept a different answer. That's a personal preference, but one that's open to review by readers. But lets be clear, the answer you accepted does _not_ give the same results as mine. With that answer you can load all blanks and your code doesn't know the difference, mine you cant. As a side not, _I am aware_ that `[A-z]` can match stuff not in `[A-Za-z] `, are you aware of that ? Might as well use `[\S\s]` which will also match.